# Need help in calling cordova plugin in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have an requirement of implementing encrypting password in Angular JS using cordova plugin. As the cordova call is asynchronous, the function that calls the plugin doesn't wait until the plugin finishes the execution.

```
var getInputParams = function(){
    for(var key in encryptedKeys){
        paramValue = encryptedKeys[key];
        encrypt(paramValue);
        alert("cipher Text:"+$rootScope.cipherText);
        cipherText = $rootScope.cipherText;
   }

    function encrypt(param) {
        cordova.exec(function(success){
            $rootScope.cipherText = success;
            alert("Encryption done");
        },function(err){
            alert(err);
        },"ParamEncryptor","encrypt",[param]);
    };
```

In the above code, the alert in the `getParameters()` comes first and then the alert in `encrypt()`. Due to this `cipherText` is assigned with `null` value. I tried implementing using defer and promise but didn't succeed. May be my implemention might be wrong. It would of great help if someone suggests any solution to the above problem.

Comment: why can't you just move the cipherText value assignment code inside success callback of encrypt()

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I tried that too. the success callback is executing after getInputParams() executes and by that time, my form is getting submitted to server with null values. I need to make some changes such that the success call back completes execution before the assignment starts.

Comment: Oh ok. Could you explain what plugin are you using? Becaus cordova.exec code will be used inside the plugin but mostly not in our project code.Could you help understand this?

Comment: I tried configuring the cordova call in plugin.js and making an call to that configuration. Still facing the same issue.

Comment: Padron me. I still dont understand the complete picture of what are you trying to acheive.